# Why probability of intersection of independent events cannot be attained by multiplying

Tags: probability

In the following sum :-
In a hostel 60% students read english newspaper and 40% students read french newspaper and 20% read both. Find the probablity that the student does not read any newspaper.

I know how to solve the problem using laws of probability but my question is that since the events are independent why cant we get the intersection by multiplying the probabilities  i.e. (4/10 * 6/10 = 24/100 but given 20/100). Why in other sums I get the intersection correctly by multiplying the probabilities of independent events but in this sum (although the intersection is given in the question itself) I get the intersection incorrect. I want to understand the concept and this is frustrating me.

Comment: Given that 24/100 is not 20/100, how dare you *assume* that the events are independent?

Comment: They aren't independent. $20\% \ne 60\% \cdot 40\%$!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen do you mean that if the intersection was not given in the question then I could have assumed that they are independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, the events just aren't independent. Only if 
$$P(A\cap B) = P (A) P (B)$$
is true, we call $A$ and $B$ independent.

A more intuitive approach is to realize that $33,3\%$ ($20/60$) of the students reading an english newspaper also read a french one while $50\%$ ($20/40$) of the students reading a french paper also read an english one. This means that if you pick a random student, the probability whether or not he reads a french newspaper "changes" with the fact that you already know that he reads an english newspaper.  Hence, the events are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

A graphical demonstration, to perhaps aid intuition:

[image]

where red denotes French newspaper readers, blue denotes English newspaper readers and purple denotes readers of both.

All of these are possible distributions of reading preference where 40% of students read the French newspaper and 60% read the English. The fact that they read one has no impact on whether they read the other.

If each student has a 0.60 probability of reading the English newspaper and a 0.40 probability of reading the French, it's most likely that 0.24 will read both. It's possible for this to not happen, however, due to noise that would be readily apparent in sample sizes as small as 100 students. Even if the events were independent, it is still *possible* for a 0.20 intersection. The numbers you have been provided are statistics of what has happened, not the perfect probabilities of what should.

(It would be from these statistics that you decide whether the events were independent, as you know with certainty that the distribution you obtained describes reality. Were you a researcher of newspaper reading phenomenas, you'd compare these results to the distribution that complete independence predicts (0.40, 0.24, 0.6) and see if the divergence was stronger than random noise fluctuations could account for.)